# Zoom and center on UIImage inside UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

I need help for scaling an image then re centering it to given point. 
[image]

So when user click for example on first name : I want to zoom and center the image on first name.

Here's my code so far :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let _image = self.image else {
        return
    }


    //Get rect of the image inside the ImageView
    let imageRect   = self.getImageRect()

    // Calculate the scale ratio
    let ratioHeight =  _image.size.height / imageRect.size.height
    let ratioWidth  = _image.size.width / imageRect.size.width
    let aspect = fmin(ratioWidth, ratioHeight)

    // get the coordinates (x,y)
    let xA4 = array[indexPath.row].coords[0]
    let yA4 = array[indexPath.row].coords[1]

    // Convert (x,y) into my current plan
    let x  = xA4 / aspect + imageRect.origin.x
    let y  = yA4 / aspect + imageRect.origin.y

    NSLog("xA4 : \(xA4) ------ x : \(x)")
    NSLog("yA4 : \(yA4) ------ y : \(y)")

    //Apply transformation
        var transform =  CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: imageView.center.x - x , y: imageView.center.y - y)
//        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
        self.imageView.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)

    }
```

The problem is that the image is scaled correctly but it's re-centred in wrong position not to the point I gave `coord`

So what I've missed ? why is not zooming or the right place ?

 
**UPDATE** 
 
To be more clear how I use try to find out the translate coords:

1. Get the rect of my displayed image not the
   imageView.
2. Then find the scale value
3. Convert the coords sent by server to coordinates that match my curent imageSize and position.
4. Then recenter the image

Is this correct ? Because it's not working and also if I click twice on first name the image is translated twice, normally it should be one time. Since it's already on the same centred on same point.

Answer (score 1):

In your CODE 2 example you are replacing `transform` each time with a new one so only the last transform is applied. Try something like:

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
transform = transform.translatedBy(x: coord.x, y: coord.y)
self.imageView.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
```

Also be aware of the order you apply these transforms

Comment: Thank you but still have problem in re-centring

Answer (score 1):

As of now its overriding with the latest and thats why only `translationX` is applying.

You have to use like this :

```
var transform =  CGAffineTransform.identity
transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 3, y: 3)
transform = transform.translatedBy(x: coord.x, y: coord.y)
self.imageView.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
```

Comment: Thank you but still have problem in re-centring